# CKEditor Defining Custom Toolbar

Tags: javascript, jquery, ckeditor, rich-text-editor

I am using CKEditor and have defined a custom toolbar in the config.js file.

However, this custom toolbar does not appear when I refresh the page where I have the CKEditor appearing.

Below is my custom toolbar in the config.js file.

```
CKEDITOR.editorConfig = function( config )
{
    // Define changes to default configuration here. For example:
    // config.language = 'fr';
    // config.uiColor = '#AADC6E';
    config.toolbar = 'Custom';

    config.toolbar_Custom =
    [
        { name: 'document', items : [ 'NewPage','Preview' ] },
        { name: 'clipboard', items : [ 'Cut','Copy','Paste','PasteText','PasteFromWord','-','Undo','Redo' ] },
        { name: 'editing', items : [ 'Find','Replace','-','SelectAll','-','Scayt' ] },
        { name: 'insert', items : [ 'Image','Table','HorizontalRule','Smiley','SpecialChar','PageBreak'
                 ,'Iframe' ] },
                '/',
        { name: 'styles', items : [ 'Styles','Format' ] },
        { name: 'basicstyles', items : [ 'Bold','Italic','Strike','-','RemoveFormat' ] },
        { name: 'paragraph', items : [ 'NumberedList','BulletedList','-','Outdent','Indent','-','Blockquote' ] },
        { name: 'links', items : [ 'Link','Unlink','Anchor' ] },
        { name: 'tools', items : [ 'Maximize','-','About' ] }
    ];
};
```

Is there anything else that I need to do other than just adding the toolbar to the config file.

Thanks for your time and help.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There are two things that could be happening. One, your config.js file could be cached, so it's loading the previous file from before your changes were made, in which case you need to either clear your browser cache or hit ctrl-F5 in your browser to fully reload your page. Or two, you're using a combo-loaded (and minified) config.js file, which would mean that you need to run the packaging tool every time you make changes to the file. See [this](http://docs.cksource.com/CKEditor_3.x/Developers_Guide/CKPackager) for more info on the packaging tool. Hope that helps!

Comment: thanks, I'll give that a go and see what happens. I beleive it might be packaging as I ran it with cleared cache on incognito mode...

Comment: it turns out that the error was with caching. I just realized the new tab I opened wasn't in incognito mode.

Comment: Thank you very much. Saved me a lot of time :D

Comment: No prob! Had quite a few problems with caching myself when I started using CKEditor. :)